# Knockout.js foreach on list of items not displaying

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This does not work

```
                <div data-bind="foreach:nonAdminIB">
                    <div><span data-bind="text: explanation"></span>&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
```

This does display the data but I have hard coded the index numbers and I don't really know how many items there will be.

```
                <div><span data-bind="text: nonAdminIB[0].explanation"></span>&nbsp;</div>
                <div><span data-bind="text: nonAdminIB[1].explanation"></span>&nbsp;</div>
```

Here is the data being sent to the browser

```
  "nonAdminIB": {
    "0": {
      "nonAdminIrregularBehaviorId": 383,
      "irregularBehaviorId": 5,
      "irregularBehaviorDescription": "Falsified Information",
      "explanation": "Falsification of information on applications/scheduling permits."
    },
    "1": {
      "nonAdminIrregularBehaviorId": 384,
      "irregularBehaviorId": 6,
      "irregularBehaviorDescription": "Falsified Score",
      "explanation": "Falsification of score information. "
    }
```

How do I get the foreach to work?

Comment: Are your div tags truly not matched up for is that just a typo?

Comment: working sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26310/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nonAdminIB` is currently an object and `foreach` works only on arrays.

You have to transform it to array:

```
var nonAdminIBArray = [];

for(var prop in nonAdminIB) {
  if(nonAdminIB.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    nonAdminIBArray.push(nonAdminIB[prop]);
  }
}
```

then use `nonAdminIBArray` with knockout.

Answer (score 1):

The foreach binding expects that the thing you are binding to is an array (observable or otherwise) rather than a JSON object. This works:

```
var vm = {
    nonAdminIB: [{
        "nonAdminIrregularBehaviorId": 383,
            "irregularBehaviorId": 5,
            "irregularBehaviorDescription": "Falsified Information",
            "explanation": "Falsification of information on applications/scheduling permits."
    }, {
        "nonAdminIrregularBehaviorId": 384,
            "irregularBehaviorId": 6,
            "irregularBehaviorDescription": "Falsified Score",
            "explanation": "Falsification of score information. "
    }]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

So if you can iterate over your JSON object and convert it to an array this will work for you. I would say, if you are going to iterate over it anyway it might be worth you taking that array and then loading it into an observable array whilst you're at it to allow you to change it client side and enjoy the knockout binding goodness.

As for why the explicit call to nonAdminIB[x] was working that would be because of the naming of your JSON object. The numbers in quotes was making it possible for you to access the object like it was an array with the square bracket notation despite the fact that the object was not, in fact, an array at all.